# Call Dynamic value in panelgrid instead of datatable

Tags: primefaces

I want to call dynamic value in panelgrid instead of datatable. In datatable I am getting dynamic value but I want to call dynamic value in panelgrid. If anyone know how to access dynamic value in panelgrid, then give me answer.

java class:

```
  public List<Student> getStuDetails() {
            Transaction trns = null;
            students = new ArrayList<Student>();        
            Session session = getSession();
            try {
                trns = session.beginTransaction();
                String sql = "select name,age,profession from student where sid = " + sid;
                SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("name", new StringType()).addScalar("age", new IntegerType()).addScalar("profession", new StringType());
                List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
                for (Object[] row : rows) {
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.setName(row[0].toString());
                    student.setAge(Integer.parseInt(row[1].toString()));
            student.setProfession(row[2].toString());                
                    students.add(student);
                }                      
                trns.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();           
                trns.rollback();
            } finally {
                session.flush();
                session.close();
            }
            return students;
        }
```

jsf code:

```
<p:panelGrid id="pgrid" columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel value="Name:"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Austin"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Age:"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="26"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Profession"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="job"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: You can achieve dynamic value in panelgrid with the help of variables...create getter setter of related variable and store fetching values in that variables ....after that you can call that variable in jsf code using managebean name like managebean.variables.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I try.

Comment: Please read some jsf tutorial…  considering the accepted answer, there is some basic jsf knowledge missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code and its working for me. I created three variable sname, sage and sprofession, need to create getter / setter also and here I am taking managed bean name is **"student"**.

**Updated Java Class:**

```
private String sname;
private Integer sage;
private Integer sprofession;    
public List<Student> getStuDetails() {
            Transaction trns = null;
            students = new ArrayList<Student>();        
            Session session = getSession();
            try {
                trns = session.beginTransaction();
                String sql = "select name,age,profession from student where sid = " + sid;
                SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("name", new StringType()).addScalar("age", new IntegerType()).addScalar("profession", new StringType());
                List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
                for (Object[] row : rows) {
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.setName(row[0].toString());
                    student.setAge(Integer.parseInt(row[1].toString()));
            student.setProfession(row[2].toString());                
                    students.add(student);
                }
                sname = students.get(0).setName();
                sage = students.get(0).setAge(); 
            sprofession = students.get(0).setProfession();          
                trns.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();           
                trns.rollback();
            } finally {
                session.flush();
                session.close();
            }
            return students;
        }
```

**Updated panelgrid:**

```
<p:panelGrid id="pgrid" columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel value="Name:"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{student.sname}"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Age:"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{student.sage}"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Profession"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{student.sprofession}"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

**Note:** But if you will use panelgrid instead of datatable, then in future you can't export your panelgrid data because dataexporter is not supported panelgrid or panel.

Comment: Thanks, Now getting dynamic values :) ......One more question Why dataexporter is not supported to panelgrid?

Comment: New questions in new questions please: the answer: it is just not implemented…  no need to obviously until now.

Comment: Hmmm if this is what the OP needed there is ***no*** relation to a panelgrid. All plain jsf, and the outputLabel is used wrong here in three tags.